# How should I define type of props supplied by react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a `react native` app with `navigation` stack defined:

```
 <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={NavigationLocations.SIGNUP}
            ...
            }}>
           ...
            <Stack.Screen
                name={NavigationLocations.SHEET}
                component={Sheet}
                options={
                    {
                        title: "Character sheet",
                        headerLeft: null
                    }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

This is my `navigation props` definition:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
    Signup: undefined,
    Login: undefined,
    Dashboard: undefined,
    SheetView: {sheet: ISheet}
};
```

How should I define the sheet props in the component that is receiving the `sheet` object passed by the navigation?

```
type Props = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, NavigationLocations.SHEET>

export default function Sheet({sheet}: Props) {
    const sheet = props.route.params.sheet;
```

Currently I am getting this error: `Error:(11, 32) TS2339: Property 'sheet' does not exist on type 'StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, NavigationLocations.SHEET>'.`

I am using the `NavigationLocations` enum because I generally dislike using strings as identifiers, but I think that my implementation has introduced an error here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackScreenProps` just includes the types for the props `navigation` and `route`.

```
type Props = {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, NavigationLocations.SHEET>;
    route: Route<NavigationLocations.SHEET, {
        ...;
    }>;
}
```

---

It looks like you've tried to access `sheet` as a top-level prop:

```
function Sheet({sheet}: Props) {
```

And also as a nested property:

```
const sheet = props.route.params.sheet;
```

That second one is correct.  We can take off some of the levels of nesting if we do this:

```
export default function Sheet({ navigation, route }: Props) {
  // sheet has type ISheet
  const {sheet} = route.params;
```

The enum should not be a problem as long as the value of the enum matches the key in the `RootStackParamList`.  I get a different error when it doesn't match, so that's not your issue.